# react-router-dom NavLink sub-pages

Tags: react-router-dom

I'm using NavLink menu items like this:

```
<NavLink to="/"  exact >Dashboard</NavLink>
<NavLink to="/catalog"  >Catalog</NavLink>
```

and it's working fine. My menu items are active as they should.
I would like that subpages from catalog also keep active class on catalog menu item. Subpages like:

```
/catalog/:id
/catalog/something/something-else
...etc
```

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can do somethink like this:

```
 <Route path="/catalog">
    <Route path=":subpage" element={<Element/>} />
 </Route>
```